# How can I make a unique constraint order independently on two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, unique-constraint

I'm working with an Oracle Database and I need to create a table like below.

```
MAP(Point_One, Poin_Two, Connection_weight).
```

The table represents data about a graph. I would like to create a table with a constraint that prevents the insertion of an already existing connection.

For example, the table already contains this connection:

```
Point_One | Point_Two | Connection_weight
-----------------------------------------
p_no1     | p_no2     | 10
```

And the constraint would prevent the repeated insertion of this connection, even if I try to add the points in different order. (For example: (p_no2, p_no1, 10) )

A simple UNIQUE (Point_One, Point_Two) constraint is unfortunatelly not enough. Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a function-based index

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_unique_edge
    ON map( greatest( point_one, point_two ),
            least( point_one, point_two ) );
```

I'm assuming that the data type of `point_one` and `point_two` is compatible with the Oracle `greatest` and `least` functions.  If not, you'd need a function of your own that picks the "greatest" and "least" point for your complex data type.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result easily by using trigger.

```
 create table map (point_one number, point_two number, connection_weight number)
/
 create or replace trigger tr_map before insert on map
 for each row
 declare
 c number;
   begin
     select count(1) into c from map where (point_one=:new.point_one and   point_two=:new.point_two)
     or
     (point_one=:new.point_two and point_two=:new.point_one);
     if c>0 then
     raise_application_error(-20000,'Connection line already exists');
  end if;
end;
  /
```

SQL> insert into map values (1,2,10);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into map values (2,1,10);
insert into map values (2,1,10)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-21000: error number argument to raise_application_error of -100 is out of 
range 
ORA-06512: at "C##MINA.TR_MAP", line 10 
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'C##MINA.TR_MAP'

I'm still thinking about the CHECK constraint, but yet I didn't come with decission whether it is possible or not.

Comment: This works as long as you only ever do single-row inserts using the `INSERT ... VALUES` statement.  As soon as you want to do a set-based `INSERT ... SELECT`, you'll get a mutating table exception.  In general, a row-level trigger defined on a table (`map` in this case) cannot directly query that table.  So this row-level trigger isn't allowed to query `map` generally.  You can work around that by creating a row-level trigger and a statement-level trigger and a package with a collection but that starts to get rather complicated.

Comment: In Oracle 11.2 you can create one compound trigger. However usually it is a bad idea to enforce constraints via trigger